# Cannot communicate with Apache server and tomcat after configuring Apache with SSL and cookies to httponly and secure?

Tags: apache, tomcat7, session-cookies

I have configured my Apache server to communicate with tomcat using a proxy parser(With reverse proxy as well), which has ssl enabled for Apache server not the tomcat server.
When I add the

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly;Secure
```

to `httpd.conf`, i can send request to the tomcat through proxy parser but from tomcat i cannot send request to Apache.

I have enable cookies in tomcat and Apache servers.

Before setting the cookies to `httponly` and secure it works fine. When set cookies to secure and `httponly`, I could see from developer tools that requests and responds missing the session cookies.

Why the session cookies are missing from the requests and response ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot answer, but I can confirm. I just experienced this too: Under Tomcat 7 (jre7), secure response cookies (i.e. `cookie.setSecure(true)`) are not available on subsequent requests. They re-appear when I comment out the setSecure call.